# EJB. Получение экземпляра через context.lookup()

Tags: glassfish, интерфейс, ejb

Есть EJB компонент, сервлет и одна библиотека. Все это работает на одном сервере GlassFish.

библиотека реализует всего один интерфейс, общий для ejb-компонента и клиента:

**Datable.java**

```
package ru.jcup.api;
import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface Datable {
  public String getData(String request);
}
```

В EJB-приложение так-же всего только 1 класс:
**DatableImpl.java**

```
package ru.jcup;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

import ru.jcup.api.Datable;

@Stateless
@EJB(beanInterface=Datable.class)
Public class DatableImpl implements Datable{

    @Override
    public String getData(String request) {
        return request + " Hell world!";
    }

}
```

Ну и сам сервлет:
**MyServlet.java**

```
package ru.jcup.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import ru.jcup.api.Datable;

@WebServlet("/getdata")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

      public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
          response.setContentType("text/html");

          try {
              Context context = new InitialContext();
                  Object proxy =  (Object)context.lookup("java:global/EjbServer/DatableImpl");

              System.out.println("!!!"+proxy); //<- тут выводится !!!ru.jcup.Datable_294616051
              Datable datable = (Datable)proxy; //<- исключение тут

              PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
              out.println("<h1>" + datable.getData("What is it?") + "</h1>");
          } catch (NamingException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

          PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
          out.println("<h1>Bad!</h1>");
      }
}
```

При запуске сервлета получаю вот такое исключение:

```
2016-01-12T14:41:20.250+0300|Warning: StandardWrapperValve[ru.jcup.servlet.MyServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet ru.jcup.servlet.MyServlet threw exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy222 cannot be cast to ru.jcup.api.Datable
    at ru.jcup.servlet.MyServlet.doGet(MyServlet.java:46)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Обратите внимание, что в серлете строка:

```
System.out.println("!!!"+proxy);
```

выводит в консоль "!!!ru.jcup.Datable_294616051", По идее каст должен отработать нормально, но этого не происходит. В этом и заключается вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрев внимательно на логи еще раз, заметил. Алиас jndi был таким:

```
java:global/EjbServer/DatableImpl!ru.jcup.Datable
```

а должен быть:

```
java:global/EjbServer/DatableImpl!ru.jcup.api.Datable
```

Внимательно проверил весь проект, никаких упоминаний о ru.jcup.Datable нет, везде прописано ru.jcup.api.Datable Самое странное, что генерировал Glassfish  это самостоятельно (или Eclipse).


Помогло только:

1. переименование интерфейса
2. переименование проекта интерфейса
3. переименование проекта EJB

Немного не научно, но работает.

**Указанный пример полностью рабочий. При обстоятельствах, отличных от моих, исключений не генерирует.**

Answer (score 0):

Была похожая проблема. Оказалось, что в адресе метода lookup() в конце был указан интерфейс, а нужен был сам класс.  То есть в моем случае class HelloWorldbean implements HelloWorldbeanLocal в пакете sessionbeans в проекте ServlelEJB. В лог файле нашел, что JNDI дала 2 адреса: "java:global/ServletEJB/HelloWorldbean!sessionbeans.HelloWorldbeanLocal" и "java:global/ServletEJB/HelloWorldbean!sessionbeans.HelloWorldbean". Так вот, рабочим адресом оказался второй.